# @State variable doesn't change its value or re-render the view

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to change a `@State` from its parent but nothing is changed in the view.
I have a simple `CustomView` with an enum that control its content:

```
struct CustomView: View {
    enum ViewType: String {
        case first, second, third
    }
    
    @State var viewType: ViewType
    
    var body: some View {
        content
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder private var content: some View {
        switch viewType {
        case .first:
            Text("The first view")
        case .second:
            Text("The second view")
        case .third:
            Text("The last view")
        }
    }
}
```

And a superview with a button that tries to change its `viewType` value.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let customView = CustomView(viewType: .first)
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            customView
            Button("Change") {
                customView.viewType = .second
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I shouldn't use `@State` but I had no success using `Binding` with enums.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suspicion about using a `@Binding` was correct -- the parent view should own the `@State` and pass it down to the child view.

```
enum ViewType: String {
    case first, second, third
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var viewType: ViewType = .first
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            CustomView(viewType: $viewType)
            Button("Change") {
                viewType = .second
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomView: View {
    
    @Binding var viewType : ViewType
    
    var body: some View {
        content
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder private var content: some View {
        switch viewType {
        case .first:
            Text("The first view")
        case .second:
            Text("The second view")
        case .third:
            Text("The last view")
        }
    }
}
```

In general, by the way, it's not a good idea to try to store references to `View`s like you did with `let customView = CustomView(viewType: .first)`. Instead, the `View` should be declared in the hierarchy and its state should be passed via parameters (including `@Bindings`).

Comment: That's a great explanation, thank you!